# Are a user's certificates linkable if he creates a new one?

Tags: cryptography, certificate, single-sign-on, service-provider

If I as a user interact with a service provider twice, and obtain a new certificate each time, will the service provider then be able to know that I am the same person? If yes then how?? I cant seem to find anything about this....

Comment: That's a very deep question that I want to follow.